# Maintain parameter in 1st access to 2nd access with session or cookie cakephp 2.4

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.4

```
class GroupsController extends AppController {
    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        debug($this->Session->read('selected'));  // ="c"  I expect
        debug($this->request->query('selected'));
        if ($this->request->query('selected') != null){
            $this->Session->write("selected",$this->request->query('selected'));
        }
debug($this->Cookie->read("test")); //== array('SID' => 'm3fmjpdp9c2',**I want this 'test' => 'test'**)
        if ($this->Cookie->read("test") == null){
            $this->Cookie->write("test","test");
            debug("newed");
        }
    debug($this->Cookie->read("test")); // == array(    'SID' => 'mjpdp9c2',    'test' => 'test'  )

    }
/**
 * Components
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $components = array('Paginator');

/**
 * index method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function index() {
        $this->Group->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('groups', $this->Paginator->paginate());
        debug($this->Session->read('selected'));
    }
```

this URL is cakephp/groups

1st cakephp/groups?selected=c
debug($this->Session->read('selected'));  // ="c" 
it returns

2nd cakephp/groups

I want 
debug($this->Session->read('selected'));  // ="c"  I expect

2nd time. but now null.

Comment: what "debug($this->request->query('selected'));" gives you?

Comment: cakephp/groups?selected=c like this malually

Comment: Your code works for me. Are you sure you have no other code in `AppController::beforeFilter()` or anywhere else, that does some `$this->Session->write("selected", ...`?

Comment: really!! https://github.com/koyakei/app I guess nothing.